# Mathematica gets the primitive of an integral right, but not the defined integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This problem should be really straightforward.

**First the demo that the formulas match:**

```
Clear[t, v]; q = 2; Expand[{x1 = Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), t], 
x2 = (-(1/(2*Pi)))*Integrate[(t + v/(2*Pi))^q*(1/(E^(2*Pi*t)*E^v - 1)), {v, 0, Infinity}], x1 - x2}]
```

which is visualizable below:

[image]

Now, if I insert endpoints in both integrals making them definite:

```
Clear[t, v]; q = 2; Simplify[{x1 = Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), {t, 0, Infinity}], 
x2 = (-(1/(2*Pi)))*Integrate[(t + v/(2*Pi))^q*(1/(E^(2*Pi*t)*E^v - 1)), 
   {v, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, Infinity}], x1 - x2}]
```

they no longer match, which is nuts!

[image]

Now, if I take the primitive and evaluate it at the endpoints of the integral using limits, the difference matches the right value, but the direct integral calculation in Mathematica doesn't work.
Mathematica is very frustrating at times.

Comment: You seem to be saying that in the first case you have indefinite integrals with respect to `t`, in the second case you have definite integrals. But that is not true: In the first case, there is no integration with respect to `t` at all (neither definite nor indefinite) in the definition of `x2`.

Comment: @user293787 I don't think you got the point. I meant in the first case the function f(t) doesn't have a range such as t IN (0,infty). In the second case, it does. If F(t)=Int{f(t)} according to the 2 formulas match in the first case, then by providing them with a range t IN (0,infty) in the second case, they should match as well .

Comment: [This Wolfram blog post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) might help describe what's going on. It describes why MM needs a lot more code to calculate definite integrals than indefinite integrals, and why it doesn't  simply subtracting values of the antiderivative doesn't always yield the value of the definite integral.

Comment: I have to admit I might be confused, but if you want `x1` to be the same as `x2` in the second block of expressions, shouldn't `x1=Expand[Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t)-1),{t,0,\[Infinity]}, t]]`?  You are missing an integral.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The indefinite integral is an anti-derivative

```
x1 = Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), t];
```

Verifying the anti-derivative

```
D[x1, t] == t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

However, there is an implied arbitrary constant term

```
D[x1 + c, t] == t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Consequently, the indefinite integral represents an infinite number of solutions. It is only coincidental that the constant value represented in the anti-derivative causes x1 and x2 to be equal. The apparent equality merely means that the two terms agree to within an arbitrary constant.

Subsequent use of a definite integral fixes the value of the unseen arbitrary constant and as expected, the terms differ by only a constant value.

```
Clear[t, v];
q = 2;
Simplify[{
  x1 = Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), {t, 0, Infinity}],
  x2 = (-(1/(2*Pi)))*
    Integrate[(t + v/(2*Pi))^q*(1/(E^(2*Pi*t)*E^v - 1)), {v, 0, Infinity}, {t,
       0, Infinity}],
  x1 - x2}]

(* {Zeta[3]/(4 π^3), -(1/240), 1/240 + Zeta[3]/(4 π^3)} *)
```

Mathematica is correct; you are misinterpreting the meaning of an indefinite integral (anti-derivative).

**EDIT:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]

q = 2;
```

The indefinite integral

```
x1 = Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), t];

Limit[x1, t -> Infinity] - Limit[x1, t -> 0]

(* Zeta[3]/(4 π^3) *)
```

This is identical to the definite integral

```
% === Integrate[t^q/(E^(2*Pi*t) - 1), {t, 0, Infinity}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: I beg to differ, because if constants are different they should be showing up in the first iteration of formulas. But Ill leave this here to see what the opinion of other users is.